# TortoiseSVN checkout - "sqlite disk i/o error (S10)"

Tags: sqlite, svn, tortoisesvn

I want to checkout repozitory, but I get the following:

```
Command: Checkout from file:///X:/data/repozytorium, 
         revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Updating: X:\data\repozytoriumwc  
Added: X:\data\repozytoriumwc\serwery  
Error: sqlite: disk I/O error (S10)  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: sqlite: disk I/O error (S10)  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: sqlite: unable to open database file (S14)  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: sqlite: unable to open database file (S14)  
Completed!:
```

X: is the network disk, but I have few repositories on it and they all work fine. This one is not. I can check it out to other disk but not this one. Why? 
I have all privileges to the disk as I am the admin :]

EDIT:
I've noticed it throws those errors only when checkout has to create some folders. If I didn't have any folder (like `serwery` folder) in commited files - it checkouts fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Updating: X:\data\repozytoriumwc

**NEVER** create Working Copy on Windows shared drive: share will get problems with sqlite 100%. Use **only** local drive for WCs

BTW, `file:///` access to repository on share is also **The Bad Idea (tm)**, network protocol (svn:// or http://) is **The Good Way**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Altough - I would like to have WC on shared drive, because others are only reading it. If I will work only on local - how they will know there has been changes made, even after I commit?

Comment: @Joe - they can: 1) check **repository** revision (svn ls -v URL) 2) be notified by post-commit hook 3) use web-frontend to repository (WebSVN, f.e.) and see commits 4) have own WCs and `svn up` from time to time. WC pn share is direct way to hell

Comment: There is a client-side workaround in SVN 1.8 for speed issues with WCs on shared drives: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#exclusivelocking

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger. I agree with you.

Comment: After year and a half we can say: forget SVN, use GIT ;)

Comment: @Joe - it's not perfect choice. For SVN-background Mercurial is more natural direction of evolution - you haven't to forget **all previous** experience

Comment: Yeah I wasn't dead serious but I have to say git is just the best vcs choice for us elastic and powerful

Comment: @Joe `Git == BrainDamage`

Comment: @LazyBadger that `if` wouldn't pass in our case ;) If you are happy with other vcs I'm happy for you.